# Foreach loop using phpquery

Tags: phpquery

I'm using phpquery to loop through a table and extract the contents of each  tag into their own variable.

```
foreach(pq('.body table tr') as $tag) {
  foreach(pq($tag)->find('td.fixData') as $td) {
    $x = pq($td)->text();
    echo '<p>'.$x.'</p>';
  }
}
```

However its putting every single match within a

tag

What I'd like to do is put

First second third fourth

Any ideas?

Comment: can you include the html your trying to loop through, that would make it easier

Comment: phpQuery should work like jQuery but it seems that it is not the case